# Como pegar ID de outra tabela e fazer INSERT em outra?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho duas tabelas: destinos e entrada:

- Na tabela **destinos**: id_destino(AI) e destino;
- Na tabela **entrada**: id(AI), id_destino(relation com id_destino da tabela **destinos**).

Criei uma query para inserir o primeiro campo do formulário (destino) na tabela **destinos**

```
$sqlinsert1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `destinos` VALUES('', '$destino')");
```

Criei uma segunda query para buscar a row recém criada:

```
$another_id = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `destinos` WHERE destino = '$destino'");
```

E uma terceira query para inserir os dados na tabela **entrada**:

```
 $sqlinsert2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `entrada_pt` VALUES('', '$another_id')");
```

Só que ao verificar a tabela **entrada**, nada é inserido, diferente da tabela **destinos**, que encontra-se preenchida.

Como pegar o id da primeira tabela e inserí-lo na segunda tabela?

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so] e parabéns por fazer de primeira uma pergunta bem formatada, bem explicada e com o código relevante! Nota-se que você andou *lurkando* :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Primeiro, a resposta:

Para pegar o ID da última inserção, basta usar o [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

```
$sqlinsert1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `destinos` VALUES('', '$destino')");
$id_destino = mysql_insert_id();

$sqlinsert2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `entrada_pt` VALUES('', '$id_destino')");
```

## Uma observação:

Este código não faz o mínimo sentido.

```
$another_id = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `destinos` WHERE destino = '$destino'");
```

A função `mysql_query()` não traz o `ID` do *record* inserido, mas um ponteiro para um set de resultados.

Para usar a sua 2ª query, em vez do `mysql_insert_id()`, precisaria disso:

```
$sqlselect1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `destinos` WHERE destino = '$destino'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlselect1);
if ($row)
   $another_id = $row['id'];
```

## O mais importante:

> Ninguém deveria estar usando mais as funções `mysql_` em PHP!
> Elas são inseguras* e obsoletas, e não estão mais disponíveis à partir do PHP 5.5.
> Use as funções [`mysqli_`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)!

<sub>* Na verdade as funções em si não são inseguras, mas são usadas insistentemente da pior maneira. Tem gente que troca de *lib*, mas continua a colocar as variáveis PHP diretamente dentro do SQL. O ideal é usar apenas o **[binding](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-bind-param.php)**.</sub>

Comment: Vlw man funcionou certim

Answer (score 1):

As funções mysql_* são obsoletas é recomendado o uso do mysqli ou PDO. Nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-nao-devemos-usar-funcoes-do-tipo-mysql) tem uma lista de argumentos para NÃO utiliza-las.

Para pegar o último id inserido utilize a função [mysql_insert_id()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

```
$sqlinsert1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `destinos` VALUES('', '$destino')");
$id_destino = mysql_insert_id();
$sqlinsert2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `entrada_pt` VALUES('', '$id_destino')");
```

Comment: Algum problema com a resposta? posso corrigir.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar sim!! A única diferença esta em trocar o mysql_ por mysqli_.... E colocar o link de conexão, como abaixo.

```
include 'conexao.php';

//$conn é a variavel de conexão utilizada em conexao.php

$sqlinsert1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `destinos` VALUES('', '$destino')");

$id_destino = mysql_insert_id($conn);

$sqlinsert2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `entrada_pt` VALUES('', '$id_destino')");
```